# Hamburger menu from HTML to ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to "converting" my code from HTML to ReactJS. What I tried and I couldn't make it worked is this line of code:

```
      <div className = "title-bar" data-responsive-toggle = "center_menu">
          <button className = "menu-icon" type = "button" data-toggle></button>
          <div className = "title-bar-title"></div>
      </div>
```

[image]
When I'm pressing that hamburger icon, that list "Home, Extensii etc" should appear. In HTML I made it worked fine. ReactJS it's not taking my data-responsive-toggle center_menu id. How should look the code, what is the correct syntax?
P.S.: I'm new in React, I'm trying to learn it.

Comment: I don't see any React code.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt, debugging details, specific issue, actual and expected results, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I don't know about whether you want it to look normal all the way and just have that burger on smaller screens or it's a burger menu all along but generally speaking for what you have asked, you need conditional classes to actually toggle between `display:block;` and `display:none;` and you need to handle that with the click event, so basically:

```
 <div className ="title-bar">
   <button className = "menu-icon" type = "button" onClick={this.toggleMenu}></button>
   <div className = "title-bar-title"></div>
 </div>

<div className={`example-menu ${this.isclicked}?" collapsed-menu": " closed-menu" `}>
  <ul class = "menu dropdown" data-dropdown-menu>
    <li><a href = "#">Home</a>
            ....
    <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and that's what `this.toggleMenu` does:

```
 toggleMenu() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isclicked: !state.isclicked
    }));
  }
```

needless to talk about those two classes `collapsed-menu` and `closed-menu`, they would be sth like these:

```
.collapsed-menu{
  ....
  display:block;
}
.closed-menu{
  ...
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several tutorials available on how to do it, e.g. here: https://css-tricks.com/hamburger-menu-with-a-side-of-react-hooks-and-styled-components/

Also you could use npm libraries to achieve the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

what about the css (media query), did you specify the min-width value for the display??